# UTF-8 chars reading in Android socket connection

Tags: android, utf-8, connection

I've prepared socket client connection like this:

```
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        socket.setSoTimeout(500);
        hostname = "XX.YY.ZZ.XX";
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port), 6000);
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                false);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
```

and I read data using i.e. this code:

```
               if (in.ready() == true) {
                   String message = in.readLine();
                   Log.e("MyApplication", "data=" + message);
               }
```

When I look in logcat I see **?** char instead of every national characters.
I'm sure data sending to my android application is in utf-8 charset therefore I tried to use code like this:

```
      UTF8Str = new String(message.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
```

or creating BufferReader like this:

```
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
```

but everything without success.
Can somebody help me resolve problem conversion chars to display them in logcat as nationals (my main goal is to display them in TextView). Everything worked two weeks ago but after some Ecclipse reconfiguration (I can't back to old settings) stoped.

~Artik

Comment: Your first approach is broken, but the second should be fine. Are you sure this isn't just whatever you're displaying the output of logcat on failing to display non-ASCII characters?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The same chars sending to logcat from ordinary string like: Log.e("MyApplication", "ĘĄÓ") works but the same chars obtained from server not :(

Comment: Okay, that's helpful to know. Are you able to use Wireshark to look at the exact data send over from the client? With the approach of setting the encoding in the InputStreamReader, it really should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, You are right. Thanks of using Wirehark I know that my server application sending bad data (? instead of national). Huge thanks for help!!!